# Printing Only the square sub-matrices in C

Tags: c, matrix, logic

I have a matrix, and I just want to get the square sub-matrices of a matrix[nr,nc] with a specific dimension "dim". However I got unnecessary ones too.

For instance I got all of those 3x3 sub square matrices correctly (when dim=3):

**1 2 3**

**5 6 7**

**9 0 1** . . .

But I also got those redundant ones which I do not want :

**4 6**

**8 8**

**1 9**

..................

**6**

**8**

**9**

> Here is the iteration part of my code:

```
            for (int iplus = 0; iplus < nr; iplus++) {
                for (int jplus = 0; jplus < nc; jplus++) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
                            if (((i + iplus) < nr) && ((j + jplus) < nc)) {
                                printf("%d ", matrix[i + iplus][j + jplus]);
                            }
                        }
                        printf("\n");
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Maybe change your outer loop limits so that you don't have to check `if (((i + iplus) < nr) && ((j + jplus) < nc))`.

Comment: Thank you it has worked! (I replaced nr ---> nr-dim+1     nc ---> nc-dim+1 and somehow it worked.)